# Laravel 5.3 on MAMP?

Tags: laravel-5, mamp

Is it possible to install laravel 5.3 on MAMP, instead of with vagrant and a VM? If so, is there a tutorial floating around somewhere? I've tried doing it myself, and it's not working out the way I thought it would.

I'm on a macbook pro, BTW.

Comment: MAMP for OS X or Windows.

Comment: OS X Sorry, I should've mentioned that.

Comment: Since you didn't specify the exact problem, I guess all you want is some link where you could follow https://telliott.io/node/969 - is it this link ? But then my guess was that you can use google also so I don't see the problem that well.

Comment: The short answer is yes. However, if you go through some of the issues you've had we can try and help you out.